# Display all records in the Track table that do not have an invoice - Comparing two tables

Tags: sql

*emphasized text*The first table is `Track`, and second table is `InvoiceLine`. They both share the column 'InvoiceId'. I tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM Track
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM InvoiceLine
    WHERE InvoiceId )
```

Comment: You **just asked** that very same question only 4 hours ago - please ***DO NOT*** repost the same question over and over again! (and you're still not providing even a shred more useful information to go on .... )

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T.* 
FROM TRACK AS T
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
   SELECT 1 FROM INVOICELINE AS L
   WHERE T.INVOICEID=L.INVOICEID
)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.